# Furnace not turning on

Tags: furnace

what does it mean when the furnace comes on right away an then off and on and that's all it does. Thanks for the answer in advance

Comment: Many different possibilities. What make/model of furnace? How fast does it cycle? Does it eventually totally stop or does it keep cycling?

Comment: are you saying that it turns off briefly and then turns on and stays on? ... or does it continue to cycle?

Comment: gas or electric?

Comment: It shall try 4 times to run, than it takes a 30 minutes break before next attempt by design.

Comment: As for why is it going on/off, it is usually bad flame sensor that supposed to report the flame is on but it does not. Flame sensors are cheap and easy to replace.

Comment: @Ruskes 4x then 30 minutes is likely specific to a particular brand or type of furnace. Which is why we need to know the make/model.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact correct, some do 3x and 20 minutes, but all have same sequence

Comment: Model number isg6r9909-06431, Gas. Inducer keeps going on and off and it won't stop